# Sorting CSV by numerical column to output top 5

Tags: csv

Hi I am trying to sort a CSV file after I write it to so that I can display the top 5 scores (winner). I can get the first 5 to print but they are not the highest scores.

```
def main():
    setup()
    print('Player 1 log in:')
    user1 = login()
    print('Player 2 log in: ')
    setup()
    user2 = login()
    print(user1, 'vs', user2)
    (player1, player1_win), (player2, player2_win) = game(user1, user2)
    if player1_win:
        winner = (user1, player1)
    else:
        winner = (user2, player2)
    print('Well done,', winner[0],' you won with ', winner[1], ' Points')
    with open('Leaderboard.csv', 'a', newline='') as file:  
        wr = csv.writer(file)
        wr.writerow((winner))
    with open('Leaderboard.csv', 'r', newline='') as file:
        score_list = list(csv.reader(file))
        print('\n', 'The top five players are: ', '\n')
        for row in islice(score_list, 5):
            print(*row)
            file.close()
```

Comment: Just show the contents of your `'Leaderboard.csv'`. Anything else is irrelavant to your question.

Answer (score 0):

When working with CSV files, it is much easier to use pandas

```
import pandas as pd
board = pd.read_csv("Leaderboard.csv")
board.sort_values(by="Score").head()
```

I highly recommend for you to check the community tutorial:
[pandas tutorial (reshape table layout)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/intro_tutorials/07_reshape_table_layout.html)

Comment: Thankyou, I will check out panda. I used the following and it seemed to work. Will panda potentially reduce my lines of code?    `

  
            score_list = list(csv.reader(file))
            sort = sorted(score_list,key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)

Comment: Yes, in my case panda has shortened my code base by a lot